# How does such a weak tractive force produce the large movements of water which happens in tides?

Tags: forces

I understand that the tides are caused by the horizontal or ***tractive*** force drawing water across the Earth’s surface For example,  https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/restles3.html states that:

*The tide-raising force exerted at a point on the Earth's surface by the Moon … is only about one 9-millionth part of the force of earth-gravity exerted toward its centre …). The tide raising force of the Moon, is, therefore, entirely insufficient to "lift" the waters of the earth physically against this far greater pull of earth's gravity. Instead, the tides are produced by that component of the tide-raising force of the moon which acts to draw the waters of the earth horizontally over its surface…. Since the horizontal component is not opposed in any way to gravity …. it becomes the effective force in generating tides.*

*At any point on the Earth's surface, the tidal force produced by the Moon's gravitational attraction may be …resolved into two components of force*

- *one…perpendicular to the Earth's surface* -
- *the other horizontal or tangential to the Earth's surface.*

*This second component… is the actual mechanism for producing the tides. The force is zero at the points on the Earth's surface directly beneath and on the opposite side of the Earth from the moon …. Any water accumulated in these locations by tractive flow from other points on the earth's surface tends to remain in a stable configuration, or tidal bulge*

**The problem I struggle to  understand is as follows...**

The tractive force is very weak of the order $10^{-7}$ g, Therefore, if we consider a given  mass of water, due to the action of this tractive force it would be given an acceleration of only $10^{-6}$ m/s$^2$. After being accelerated for six hours it would have a delta v of only 0.02 m/s - a very small quantity.

I probably missing something obvious but I’m not sure what it is!!
How does such a weak force produce the large movements of water seen  in tides?

Comment: "Tractive force is the force needed to overcome the resistance caused by friction when two bodies slide or roll on each other. Compared to the resistance generated by friction, tractive force has the same intensity and the same sense, but the opposite direction." https://www.elesa.com/en/CatalogoDatiTecniciUS/43-tractive-force . I think the numbers you quote are the force needed to overcome the resistance  that the tide meets, not the force that moves the tide.https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/13-6-tidal-forces has tidal forces for a 1kg mass in newtons

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Earthscience.SE].